# Disable the interactive-search - user side

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk3, gtk2

I got accustomed to then I write file name in Save dialog in Windows PC, it writes into file name label. In linux I must focus on label, and then write. It's annoying, but I can't find how to disable quick search. I see source, GTK documentation, asking questions to developers, but no help. There is this mice hidden? GTK2-3, no matter.
In the answers on this site I see recomendations for developers, not users. I want recompile GTK, or write the key in .gtkrc-2.0/3.0 to disable this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I found, that GTK developers is very hard of hearing, and don't like adding configurable options. 
This "feature" is called typeahead and hardcoded in GTK libs, so no config or build options, just fixing code needed. It's a pity...
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/33x4wk/gnomegtk_316_file_chooser_typeahead/
But I find filename and strings to modify:
/gtk+-3.22.7/gtk/gtkfilechooserwidget.c b/gtk+-3.22.7/gtk/gtkfilechooserwidget.c
gtk_tree_view_set_search_column (GTK_TREE_VIEW (priv->browse_files_tree_view), -1);

/gtk+-3.22.7/gtk/ui/gtkfilechooserwidget.ui b/gtk+-3.22.7/gtk/ui/gtkfilechooserwidget.ui
0

Now need find source of GTK, because there is no option to disable this behavior...